# convert a dictionary of pandas date frame into one excel file with different sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a dictionary where the keys are names of pandas data frames and the items are the data frames themselves. I want to save this file into an excel file with different sheets, where the name of each sheet is one key of the dictionary and the data inside the sheet is the item (data frame) corresponding to that key.
So let say the dictionary is `dict = {df_1: dataframe_1, df_2: dataframe_2, ...}`, I want to convert this into one excel file with sheet one name is df_1 and the data inside is dataframe_1, etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` function provides the parameter `sheet_name` which can be used to specify the name of the excel sheet in which the dataframe is to be written. Use

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    for k in df_dict:
        df_dict[k].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=k)
```

Note that it is better to use an `pd.ExcelWriter` here to avoid opening and closing the file unnescessarily.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has a built-in `to_excel()` function:

```py
df.to_excel()
```

And, per their documentation, you can define an `ExcelWriter` that writes to multiple sheets.

> To write a single object to an Excel .xlsx file it is only necessary to
> specify a target file name. To write to multiple sheets it is necessary to
> create an `ExcelWriter` object with a target file name, and specify a sheet
> in the file to write to.

> Multiple sheets may be written to by specifying unique `sheet_name`.
> With all data written to the file it is necessary to save the changes.
> Note that creating an `ExcelWriter` object with a file name that already
> exists will result in the contents of the existing file being erased.

You end with something like this (updated with Arnau's iterator, but follows the docs):

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:
    for k in df_dict:
        df_dict[k].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=k)
```

Comment: Hi lil-solbs, welcome to stack overflow. Btw. it is generaly considered bad form to copy from someones elses answer without credit.

Comment: You did beat me to the punch. I did not intend to steal. I liked your iterator and that is the only change I made (not sure if you can see the edit history). I even left the variable `k` to not hide the theft, but I wanted the other paragraphs from the docs in case they were helpful